# How to delete all MySQL rows except one after ordering them by groups and date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

[image]

I want to create a stored procedure that would delete all records but only keep the latest ones (having the newest Last_Warning_Message) for each Application_Id and External_Account_Id. So after executing the stored procedure, the table should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `join` in the `delete`:

```
delete t
    from thistable t join
         (select Application_Id, External_Account_Id, 
                 max(Last_Warning_Message) as max_Last_Warning_Message
          from thistable t
          group by Application_Id, External_Account_Id
         ) tt
         on t.Application_Id = tt.Application_Id and
            t.External_Account_Id = tt.External_Account_Id and
            t.Last_Warning_Message < tt.max_Last_Warning_Message;
```